# how to fix the height of bars in flutter horizontal bar charts

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In flutter charts, the horizontal chart automatically stretches according to the height of the screen. Is there any way through which I may fix the height of the bars so that it may not stretch to the entire screen?

Comment: can you share the code part where you are implementing `charts` ?

Comment: @MazinIbrahim the code is like this 

https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/bar_charts/horizontal_pattern_forward_hatch
and the library I am using is 'charts_flutter 0.5.0'

Comment: @Sadaf did you find a resolution for this?  I'm just coming across this question for myself

Answer (score 0):

Simple add your chart in the ConstrainedBox like this -

```
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(height: 200.0), // give the height according to you
   child : Your_Chart_here(), // your chart here
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap `BarChart` in to `SizedBox` (to set size), wrapped with `SingleChildScrollView` (to scroll it).

## In pseudocode

```
- SingleChildScrollView
       - SizedBox
              - charts.BarChart
```

## Flutter

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 2000,
    child: HorizontalBarLabelChart(
      getData(),
    ),
  ),
),
```

## Size calculation

Height of the `SizedBox` can be calculated base on number of data, e.g.:

```
numerOfElements * 50
```

## Before

For 100 elements

[image]

## After

For 100 elements (so height is `5000` because `100 * 50`)

[image]